# can not open vscode in osx after config language

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode on macbook. I just set my vscode language from 'en' to 'zh-cn', and restart it. After that , i can't start my vscode anymore. Re install vscode does not work too

Answer (score 0):

I hava fixed this problem.

```
/Users/gaven/Library/Application Support/Code/User/locale.json
```

Edit this file . I used 'zh_cn' , so this problem happened. Change it to 'zh-cn',then...